# Editing Values in XML using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, linux, bash, xmlstarlet

I'm new using xmlstarlet, as i got to no point using bash.

I try to replace many values in an XML file at once.

What i tried was:

> xmlstarlet ed -L -u "/items/item/property[@name='Stacknumber']/@value"
>   -v '30000' items.xml

```
<items>    
   <item name="foodEggBoiled">
      <property name="Stacknumber" value="50"/> <!-- This i want to change-->
    </item>
    <item name="foodEggRaw">
      <property name="Stacknumber" value="1"/> <!-- and this not-->
    </item>
</items>
```

The value i want to change is

```
<property name="Stacknumber" value="50"/>
```

I want to change every value from the property Stacknumber with a value above 1 to 30000 like

```
<property name="Stacknumber" value="30000"/>
```

But I don't know how to select only properties with values above 1.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your root in the XML shown (as of [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53572089/3) is `item`, where the query looks for `items`. It would also be helpful to try to build a proper [mcve] -- note the **M**inimal part of that specification, meaning anything unrelated to the problem shouldn't be shown (and the **C**omplete / **V**erifiable specs, meaning that the code shown should be complete enough someone can see the problem -- maybe you should include *two different* "Stacknumber"s, one that should be changed and one that shouldn't, to be complete enough that answers can be tested).

Comment: Sorry for all the mess - i'm completely new to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **valid** XML:

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl --update '//property[@name="Stacknumber"][@value>"1"]/@value' -v '30000' file.xml
```

If you want to edit file inplace, add option -L.

Output:

```
<items>
  <item name="foodEggBoiled">
    <property name="Stacknumber" value="30000"/>
    <!-- This i want to change-->
  </item>
  <item name="foodEggRaw">
    <property name="Stacknumber" value="1"/>
    <!-- and this not-->
  </item>
</items>
```